# How would I port this delphi 7 prog to .net (C#)?

Tags: c#, .net, delphi, delphi-2009, delphi-7

http://forums.alliedmods.net/showthread.php?t=64767

The source acts like its missing a ton of stuff I can't find like uh TBX and some other things

I don't really know the language, but I have hoping I could get it to compile with delphi 2009/2010.net and then see about porting its IL. (to C# I guess)

The reasoning behind this is because pawnstudio is crash happy but the program (layout, syntax highlighting, the fact that the intellisense (clamsense) works with functions from includes, in the file, etc) is really easy to use.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I always wonder why people thinking porting a buggy program will mysteriously fix bugs. The problem are not the tools, it is the one holding the tools.

Comment: @Marco: didn't you know that C# code cannot contain bugs? :)

Comment: I mean maybe it would be better to just try and get it to compile with the newest delphi lol
but then theres still the problem of why it won't compile from source because of missing packages

Comment: I had no idea that told me -_-
omfg I feel like such a noob.

Comment: If you don't know the language, and you don't want to, consider hiring someone else to do this job for you.  If you want to learn, start providing the name of the missing units/packages and try to spend more time writing your questions.

Comment: Or maybe just write the whole thing from scratch in C# it might be easier

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is a really, really **bad idea**. *Stabilize first, then port* (if needed). Porting introduces problems, and it is not nice when you cannot tell if the bug is existing or new.

[edit] I've downloaded the source. It is not what I'd call modern, well-refactored Delphi code. Long functions, no object-orientation visible, all code in the form event handlers.
TBX you can find at [Torry](http://www.torry.net/pages.php?id=16)

Comment: I don't know the language and like I said the source acts like its missing stuff
I can't even compile it :/
It would be easier to fix in c# and redoing the interface (from other answer) wouldn't be that hard.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Delphi 7 you're using the VCL/various components native to delphi.
Those are NOT present in c# (in Delphi 2009/2010 probably yes), so you can't do a naive port, you will need to redo most of the program. (at least the interface part)

Answer (score 1):

TBX is not yet supported but you can look at [spTBX](http://www.silverpointdevelopment.com/)

It will not be very easy to port in C#.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know Delphi, you ought to get someone who does to help out.  Delphi's an easier language to work with than most, but like any language it has subtleties, complexities and dark corners.  If you try to port it without the necessary domain knowledge, then not only are you reinventing the wheel, you're reinventing it half-blind.  Especially if you're not able to compile the original and test it.

What units does it say are missing, BTW?